# The set of functions which map convergent series to convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f$ is some real function with the above property, i.e.

if $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty {x_n}$ converges, then $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty {f(x_n)}$ also converges.

My question is: can anything interesting be said regarding the behavior of such a function close to $0$, other than the fact that $f(0)=0$?

Comment: A simple example: If $\sum x_n$ converges absolutely, then any $f(x) = O(x)$ has the desired property.

Comment: All I can think is that , if the space you're in is complete, uniformly-continuous functions take Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences. This allows a unique continuous extension for functions defined in dense subsets.And continuous alone is not enough for this last, as f(x)=1/(x-2^{1/2}) is an example.

Comment: Let me ask this: must $f$ be continuous at $0$?

Comment: I misread your question so deleted the comment I posted.

Comment: Are your spaces--initial and target--complete, or do you want a more general result for any spaces? From your f(0)=0, I assume your maps are from R to R?

Comment: Yes, $f$ goes from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Let me also mention that what I am primarily interested in, is whether this set of functions has some interesting universal property, such as being continuous at $0$, and if so, what the "best" such property is. For instance, can anyone come up with an example of a non-polynomial such $f$?

Comment: See also [$f$ such that $\sum a_n$ converges $\implies \sum f(a_n)$ converges](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332433/f-such-that-sum-a-n-converges-implies-sum-fa-n-converges)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'm quite late on this one, but I think the result is nice enough to be included here.

**Definition** A function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is said to be *convergence-preserving* (hereafter *CP*) if $\sum f(a_n)$ converges for every convergent series $\sum a_n$.

**Theorem ([Wildenberg](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322761)):** The CP functions are exactly the ones which are linear on some neighbourhood of $0$.

**Proof ([Smith](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324271)):** Clearly, whether $f$ is CP only depends on the restriction of $f$ on an arbitrary small neighbourhood of $0$. Since the linear functions are CP, the condition is clearly sufficient. Let's prove that it is also necessary.

We will prove two preliminary results.

*Lemma 1:* $f$ CP $\Rightarrow$ $f$ continuous at $0$.

*Proof:* Let's suppose that $f$ isn't continuous at 0. This implies that there exists a sequence $\epsilon_n \to 0$ and a positive real $\eta > 0$ such that $\forall n, |f(\epsilon_n)| \geq \eta$. But it is easy to extract a subsequence $\epsilon_{\phi(n)}$ such that $\sum \epsilon_{\phi(n)}$ converges (take $\phi$ such that $\epsilon_{\phi(n)} \leq 2^{-n}$, for instance). For such a subsequence, we still have that $|f(\epsilon_{\phi(n)})| \geq \eta$. This prevents $\sum f(\epsilon_{\phi(n)})$ to converge and, thus, $f$ to be CP, a contradiction.

*Lemma 2:* The function $(x, y) \mapsto f(x+y) + f(-x) + f(-y)$ vanishes on some neighbourhood of $0$.

*Proof:* If it didn't, one would be able to find sequences $x_n \to 0$ and $y_n \to 0$ s.t. $\forall n, f(x_n + y_n) + f(-x_n) + f(-y_n) \neq 0$. Up to some extraction, we can assume that $\delta_n = f(x_n + y_n) + f(-x_n) + f(-y_n)$ always has the same sign (let's say $\delta_n > 0$, for the sake of simplicity.)

Consider now the series $$\begin{array}{l@{}l}
(x_0 + y_0) &+ (-x_0) + (-y_0) +  \cdots + (x_0 + y_0) + (-x_0) + (-y_0)\\ 
& +(x_1 + y_1) + (-x_1) + (-y_1) +  \cdots + (x_1 + y_1) + (-x_1) + (-y_1)\\
&+\cdots\\
&+(x_n + y_n) + (-x_n) + (-y_n) +  \cdots + (x_n + y_n) + (-x_n) + (-y_n)+\cdots,
\end{array}$$
where every triplet of termes $(x_i+y_i) + (-x_i) + (-y_i)$ is repeated $M_i > 0$ times, for some integer $M_i > 0$.

Because $x_n \to 0$ and $y_n \to 0$ and the three terms $x_i + y_i, -x_i, -y_i$ add to 0, it is easy to see that this series is convergent, regardless of the choice of the $M_i$'s.

On the other hand, if we choose $M_i \geq \delta_i^{-1}$, the image of our series by $f$ is $$\begin{array}{l@{}l}
f(x_0 + y_0) &+ f(-x_0) + f(-y_0) +  \cdots + f(x_0 + y_0) + f(-x_0) + f(-y_0)\\ 
& +f(x_1 + y_1) + f(-x_1) + f(-y_1) +  \cdots + f(x_1 + y_1) + f(-x_1) + f(-y_1)\\
&+\cdots\\
&+f(x_n + y_n) + f(-x_n) + f(-y_n) +  \cdots + f(x_n + y_n) + f(-x_n) + f(-y_n)+\cdots,
\end{array}$$
which diverges, for every line adds to $M_i \delta_i > 1$. Again, this in direct contradiction with the CPness of $f$.

If we apply the result of lemma 2 with $y = 0$, we get that $f(-x) = -f(x)$. So we can rewrite lemma 2 in the following way:
$\exists \eta > 0 : \forall x, y \in (-\eta, \eta), f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$.

This property and the continuity at 0 imply first the continuity on the whole of $(-\eta, \eta)$ and it is then not hard to adapt the [classical proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356645/i-need-to-find-all-functions-f-mathbb-r-rightarrow-mathbb-r-which-are-conti) to show that $f$ is linear on $(-\eta, \eta)$. Q.E.D.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean, in applying lemma 2, that $f(-x)=-f(x)$? Hard to see how you'd get $f(x)=-x$.

Comment: You're absolutely right, of course. I fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

If $f$ is not continuous at $0$, then we can find a sequence $x_n$ that converges to $0$ but $f(x_n)$ doesn't converge to $0$. First get a subsequence $y_n$ of $x_n$ with $|f( y_n)| > r$ for some $r>0$. Next choose some subsequence $z_n$ of $y_n$ so that
$\sum z_n$ converges. However the series $\sum f(z_n)$ diverges and it follows that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Ok, next question: must $f$ be differentiable at $0$?

Answer (score -1):

Answer to the *next* question: **no**.

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
n\,x & \text{if } x=2^{-n}, n\in\mathbb{N},\\
x & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=f(0)=0$, $f$ transforms convergent series in convergent series, but $f(x)/x$ is not bounded in any open set containing $0$. In particular $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. This example can be modified to make $f$ continuous.

**Proof.**

Let $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ be a convergent series. Let $I=\{k\in\mathbb{N}:x_k=2^{-n}\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. For each $k\in I$ let $n_k\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $x_k=2^{-n_k}$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(x_k)=\sum_{k\in I} n_k\,2^{-n_k}+\sum_{n\not\in I} x_n.
$$
The series $\sum_{k\in I} n_k\,2^{-n_k}$ is convergent. It is enough to show that also $\sum_{n\not\in I} x_n$ is convergent. This follows from the equality
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=\sum_{n\in I} x_n+\sum_{n\not\in I} x_n
$$
and the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ is convergent and $\sum_{k\in I} x_n$ absolutely convergent.

**The proof is wrong. $\sum_{k\in I} x_n$ may be divergent.** Consider the series
$$
\frac12-\frac12+\frac14-\frac14+\frac14-\frac14+\frac18-\frac18+\frac18-\frac18+\frac18-\frac18+\frac18-\frac18+\dots
$$
It is convergent, since its partial sums are
$$
\frac12,0,\frac14,0,\frac14,0,\frac18,0,\frac18,0,\frac18,0,\frac18,0,\dots
$$
The transformed series is
$$
\frac12-\frac12+\frac24-\frac14+\frac24-\frac14+\frac38-\frac18+\frac38-\frac18+\frac38-\frac18+\frac38-\frac18+\dots
$$
whose partial sums are
$$
\frac12,0,\frac12,\frac14,\frac34,\frac12,\frac78,\frac34,\frac98,1,\frac{11}8,\frac54,\dots
$$
which grow without bound.

---

On the other hand, $f(x)=O(x)$, the condition in Antonio Vargas' comment, is not enough when one considers series of arbitrary sign. Let
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x\cos\dfrac{\pi}{x} & \text{if } x\ne0,\\
0 & \text{if } x=0,
\end{cases}
\quad\text{so that }|f(x)|\le|x|.
$$
Let $x_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges, but
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n
$$
diverges.

Comment: Can you please provide a short proof why $f$ sends convergent series to convergent series?

Comment: I have written the proof.

Comment: Not sure $\sum\limits_{k\in I}n_k/2^{n_k}$ always converges. Consider $(x_i)_{i\geqslant1}$ such that every $x_i$ is a negative power of $2$ and assume that $x_i=1/2^k$ roughly $2^k/k^2$ times. Then $\sum\limits_{i\geqslant1}x_i\approx\sum\limits_{k\geqslant1}1/k^2$ converges but $\sum\limits_{i\geqslant1}f(x_i)\approx\sum\limits_{k\geqslant1}1/k$ diverges.

Comment: Aside from Didier's point above, are you certain you can split the series?