# Uniqueness of the endomorphism of the multiplicative group of positive real numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do we prove that the endomorphism of the multiplicative group of positive real numbers is unique (up to a complex variable)!? meaning: how do we prove that it has the following - and only the following - form:
$$f(x)=x^{s}\;\;\;\;(x\in \mathbb{R}^{+} \;\;,s\in\mathbb{C})$$

Comment: There are other endomorphisms, but these are the continuous ones. The non-continuous ones are very non-continuous. :) And $s\in\mathbb R$ is enough, I think - any $s\in\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$ yields a map $\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb C$, but they aren't endomorphisms.

Comment: This is trivially the Cauchy equational problem after passing to $\mathbb{R}$ via $\log$.

Comment: yeah, thanks, i should've mention this is the question : i want to prove that these are the only continuous endomorphism.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I apologize. It's Cauchy's functional equation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation

Comment: @MohammadAlJamal Just an English issue. You are talking about an infinite number of endomorphisms, on for every $s$, so "this is the only continuous endomorphism" is confusing. "These are the only continuous endomorphisms" is a better phrasing.

Comment: @AlexYoucis , but the Cauchy's functional equation doesn't have a unique solution.

Comment: @MohammadAlJamal What do you mean?

Comment: @MohammadAlJamal Neither does this problem. $s=1$ gives one endomorphism, $s=2$ gives another, $s=\pi$ gives a third, etc.

Comment: i mean in terms of the "families" of solutions .

Comment: But Cauchy only has one family of solutions, too, when restricted to continuous functions. So your objection to Alex is confusing. @MohammadAlJamal

Comment: And I'm not sure what it means to be a unique "family of solutions." That strikes me, again, as a poor use of the word "unique." What you mean is that this family is the complete set of continuous endomorphisms.

Answer (score 2):

By passing to $(\mathbb{R},+)$ using $\log$ this becomes the Cauchy functional equation. This has been beat to death on math.se Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356645/i-need-to-find-all-functions-f-mathbb-r-rightarrow-mathbb-r-which-are-conti) for example.

For other similar questions, look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation).