# Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $f(xf(y)+f(x)+y)=xy+f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, real-numbers, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for two real numbers $x$ and $y$ where $f(xf(y)+f(x)+y)=xy+f(x)+f(y)$

For $x=0$ and $y=-f(0)$ then $f(-f(0))=0$. So, there is a real root $r_0$ for function $f$.

For $x=r_0$ and $y=r_0$ we have $r_0^2=0$, so $f(0)=0$ and zero root is unique.

Please help me to complete the proof.

Comment: Taking $y=0$, we now get $f(f(x))=f(x)$, so $f$ is identity on its range.  Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: With $x=y=1$ we have $f(2f(1)+1)=1+2f(1)$. In particular $f(1) \neq 0$ because that would imply $f(1)=1$, a contradiction. The identity works so there is at least one such function.

Comment: With $x=1$ we get $f(f(y)+f(1)+y)=y+f(1)+f(y)$ so $f(y)+f(1)+y$ is a fix-point for every $y\in\mathbb{R}.$ I'm not totally sure about what we can conclude from this, but one possibility is that $f(t)=t$ for all $t.$ Another possibility is that $f(y)+f(1)+y\equiv k$ for some constant $k$ and $f(k)=k.$ This would then give $f(y)=k-f(1)-y.$

Comment: @md2perpe Your second possibility is sadly not compatible with the fact that $f(f(y)) = f(y)$ for all $y$, as $f(f(y)) = k - f(1) - (k - f(1) - y) = y$ and thus any $y \neq \frac{k - f(1)}{2}$ grants a contradiction, but good thinking anyway!

Comment: Set $x=y=-1$ and we get $f(-1)=1+2f(-1)$ and so $f(-1)=-1$.

Comment: Setting $y=f(x)$ with $f(f(x))=f(x)$ gives $f((x+2)f(x))=(x+2)f(x)$. I'm starting to think $f(x)=x$ may be the only solution and I'm looking at what happens when $f(x)-x \neq 0$ to see if I can find a contradiction.

Comment: f(x)=x is a candidate but how to prove the uniqueness?

Comment: $x=-1$ is also unique such that $f(x)=-1$. If there was another, say $f(\alpha)=-1$, then eq. with $x=-1,y=\alpha$ implies $-1=-\alpha-2$, so $\alpha=-1$.

Comment: Since $f$ is the identity on its range, I thought it'd be another appraoch to try to show that the range is $\mathbb{R}$. You can show by contradiction that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is uncountable: suppose it is countable. Then the set $E := \{f(z_1) - f(z_2) - f(z_3) | (z_1,z_2,z_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3\}$ is also countable, and so there exists $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus E$. Contradiction by taking this $x$ and $y = 1$ in our functional equation, therefore $f(\mathbb{R})$ is uncountable (and thus infinite).

Comment: And the same argument gives $f(\mathbb{R})$ unbounded.

Comment: Done, wrapped up : but a big, huge thank you to all the commenters above. Your efforts convinced me that this question was attemptable.

Comment: Very nice Sarvesh! For some reasons results did not show up in approach0, but it seems there are these aops threads https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2840807 and https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2941330_functional_equation_fxfyfxyxyfxfy . Based on that setting $x=-y/f(y)$ (for $y \neq 0$) and using $f(f(x))=f(x)$ the equation gives $f(y)^2=y^2$, and then it's actually simple to finish off ($f(y)=-y$ can be ruled out or limited to $y=0,1$ and $1$ is impossible by above comments). I'll leave someone else to write up an another answer if needed.

Comment: Thank you, @Sil, for your kind suggestion. I tried your approach and it seems to work, and because this question is bountied now, I will go to extra lengths to fill in the blanks provided by you.

Comment: @QC_QAOA Thank you very much for the bounty. I will have to improve this answer in light of your recognition, so I'll hope to do that tomorrow maybe!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

###### Introduction

I'm not really an expert at these functional equations, but it seems that I'm on a bit of a streak (two of my previous three answers come from this tag), and as everybody knows: being in flow is a wonderful thing.

The first thing I did was check Approach0 and the likes for similar questions. I didn't find the exact question anywhere, but I must admit that I found some really similar questions. However, similarity can easily count for nothing, especially with olympiad problems. That's why I'm not going to bother citing those similar problems.

I will *definitely* try and explain my thought process every step of the way so that others can also understand how to attack similar problems. I will also, briefly, step down a blind alley to illustrate a useful-looking method that I believe *will not work* for this scenario.

---

###### First thoughts and notation

When I hit this problem for the first time, I made some observations that I have here on record.

Let $P(x,y)$ be the assertion $$f(xf(y)+f(x)+y) = xy+f(x)+f(y)$$ for $x,y \in \mathbb R$. I observed that

- The right-hand side is symmetric in $x,y$.
- The left hand side is $f(\cdot)$ for some $\cdot$. Therefore, every RHS produced by $P(x,y)$ must be in the range of $f$.

---

###### On $f(0)$ and the range of $f$

Then I began with the obvious substitutions

$$
P(x,0) : f(xf(0)+f(x)) = f(x)+f(0)
$$

$$
P(0,y) : f(f(0)+y) = f(0)+f(y)
$$

$$
P(x,-f(x)) : f(xf(-f(x))) = -xf(x) + f(x) - f(-f(x))
$$

The third one is useful : using $x=0$, $P(0,-f(0))$ gives $f(-f(0)) = 0$ following cancellations.

---

###### On the uniqueness of $f(y)=0$, and the range of $f$

As the OP mentioned, $0$ has the unique preimage $0$.

Indeed, if $f(y)=0$ then $P(y,y)$ gives $y^2=0$ so that $y=0$.

We derived earlier that $f(-f(0)) = 0$. Therefore, it follows that $-f(0)=0$, hence $f(0)=0$ and $0$ is the unique such value by the previous paragraph.

Once we get this, look back at $P(x,0)$ and observe that $f(0)=0$ to see that $f(f(x))=f(x)$ for all $x$.

---

###### The range of $f$, and a blind alley

We saw that $f(f(x)) = f(x)$ is true for all $x$. We can be tempted to show that $f$ is surjective now. In this direction, I'll explain what I did, because the commenters above, who very eagerly attempted to solve this question, will be happy to know that I followed them and treated them like my gurus.

Let $x,y$ be arbitrary. Start with $P(f(x),f(y))$ and use $f(f(x))$ to get $$
f(f(x)f(y)+f(x)+f(y)) = f(x)f(y)+f(x)+f(y)
$$

That is, we've proven that under the function $g(x,y)=xy+x+y$, the range of $f$ is closed. This can be used to derive various corollaries from the comments.

Another observation can be made by plugging in $P(-1,-1)$ which gives $f(-1)=-1$. (*THIS will be truly crucial*)

One can also try to prove the following : $f(f(x)^2)= f(x)^2$ for all $x$ , and $f(-f(x)) = -f(x)$ for all $x$. Thus, we've shown that the range is closed under various operations.

However, this is actually a blind alley. While I cannot assert it with utmost confidence, observe that

- One can't attempt substitutions with rational numbers in general: try $f(\frac 12)$, for example, and see where you get. Or maybe try setting $y = \frac 1x$, and you'll have a problem. It seems that you can't get out of the integers.
- Even if you get to the rational numbers, there's no way to place any monotonicity conditions on $f$, or continuity conditions, which allow you to move from the rational numbers to the real numbers.

Therefore, attempts to make this work are likely to be futile, though I absolutely, absolutely invite everyone to try.

EDIT: It seems that Sil, in the comments, has found a way out using a clever substitution! I'll have a go and change everything I've said above if it works out.

---

###### Hitting a right approach

A right approach , in this case, comes from observing that if we expect, in light of everything we've said before, that $f(x)=x$ for $x \in \mathbb R$, then the function $g(x) = f(x)-x$ should be *identically zero* for $x \in \mathbb R$.

However, when you form the functional equation for $g(x)$, something that one may not observe in the original equation manifests itself, and we see niceties occur.

Let's do it : let $g(x) = f(x)-x$ for $x \in \mathbb R$. Start with $P(x,y)$ and begin to substitute $g$ for $f$ everywhere, knowing that $f(z) = g(z)+z$.
\begin{align}
f(xf(y)+f(x)+y) &= xy+f(x)+f(y) \\
\implies g(xf(y)+f(x)+y) + xf(y)+f(x)+y &= xy+g(x)+x+g(y)+y \\
\implies g(xg(y)+xy+g(x)+x+y)+xg(y)+xy+g(x)+x+y &= xy+g(x)+x+g(y)+y \\
\implies g(xg(y)+xy+g(x)+x+y)+xg(y) &= g(y) \\
\implies g(xg(y)+xy+g(x)+x+y) &= (1-x)g(y)
\end{align}

We make a crucial observation about $g$ now. Let's call the last identity in the chain above $P^*(x,y)$.

> Claim : if there is a $y_0$ such that $g(y_0) \neq 0$, then $g$ is *surjective*.

Proof : If $g(y_0) \neq 0$, then $g(y_0)$ belongs in the range of $g$ obviously. Let $T \in \mathbb R$ be arbitrary and let $x_0 = 1-\frac{T}{g(y_0)}$. Then, $(1-x_0)g(y_0)=T$. By observing $P^*(x_0,y_0)$, one sees that $T$ is in the range of $g$, as desired.

We will show that $g$ cannot be surjective in the next section, creating the contradiction.

---

###### An ideal choice, and a contradiction to $g$ being surjective

From surjectivity, we will now pick the most suitable candidate for the next substitution, leading to a vast simplification.

The key idea is the following : look at the left hand side of $P^*$, and you have $g(xg(y)+g(x)+xy+x+y)$. We want a value of $x$ or $y$ that can perhaps cancel a great number of terms. One such substitution is easily observed: $x=-1$. Recall that $f(-1)=-1$ (Yes, this was important!) so $g(-1) = 0$.

Now $P^*(-1,y)$ gives $$
g(-g(y)+0-y-1+y) = 2g(y) \implies g(-g(y)-1) = 2g(y)
$$

However, we mentioned that $g$ was surjective! Therefore, the above equation actually holds for all $z$ by merely substituting $y = g^{-1}(z)$ above where $y$ is any preimage of $z$.

Thus, we obtain $$
g(-z-1) = 2z
$$
for all $z$. This is a contradiction : take $z=-1$, then $g(0)=-2$ is obtained, which is a contradiction because $f(0)=0$ therefore $g(0)=0$.

Finally, we obtain that $g \equiv 0$, and $f(x) =x$ everywhere.

Comment: Looks correct to me. Good work!

Comment: @md2perpe You're welcome, and thanks for having a look and aiding me in the comments.

Comment: Good job! And yeah I don't think that trying to show $f$ to be surjective directly was gonna work, glad there was an actual solution!

Comment: @BrunoB Thank you for your feedback, and for the excellent comments below the question.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer This one is not correct. $P(x,-f(x)) : f(xf(-f(x))) = -xf(x)$. In fact $P(x,-f(x))=-xf(x)+f(x)+f(-f(x))$.

Comment: @FarshidFarhat Oh yes, thanks. I still think everything works out, but I'll take a look at that one carefully. In fact, I think things will still work with a small rectification. I'll delete and undelete this answer once it is corrected.

Comment: @FarshidFarhat Corrected. I made the mistake following incorrect replacement of $f$ by zero. Hopefully it should be okay now. To be concrete : the only results required in this proof are (i) $f(r)=0$ has the unique solution $0$ (ii) $f(-1)=-1$ (iii) The function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ , if not identically zero, must be surjective. The part prior to $f(x)=x$ may have been overlooked by previous upvoters because it was derived in the comments and verified by voters there as well.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I'll check it the rest later. Thanks.

Comment: @FarshidFarhat Thank you very much for the correction. Please let me know if anything needs to be clarified further, anytime you're free, and I'll get it done.

Comment: +1 For writing this with a view to really teaching the reader

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Very impressive solution. As my solution makes use of calculus and hence makes strong assumptions on $f(x)$ I wonder which assumptions you made explicitly or implicitly about $f(x)$? Is your solution valid for integers or can it be extended to those?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Thank you for asking, Dr. Wolfgang! It turns out that I made no analytical assumptions about $f$ : not a single one! That surprised me initially : I had expected very much an approach like the one you suggest. Furthermore, based on the initial comments, I had expected that the "common sense" approach would be to make sure that $f$ was surjective somehow, and then use $f(f(x))=f(x)$ to conclude : where I might require continuity of $f$ if I , for example, stuck to the rationals. The calculation for $g(x)=f(x)-x$ came when I realized that the right hand $(1-x)g(y)$ is nice.

Comment: (continued) Somehow, everything worked out nicely. I mentioned earlier about being in flow : I think the advantage of being in flow is that these observations are made well. I admire your work ,Dr. Wolfgang, for its versatility : I am sure it will be much more applicable than my work in general. After all, in advanced applications, functional equations are solved not in the above way but using power series and hard, rigorous estimates. A +1 from me! @FShrike Thank you for your continued support,  I needed to provide a good answer, in light of the efforts from various commentators who did well!

Comment: @Sarvesh Ravichandran Iyer Thank you very much for the explanations and your kind words. It is really surprising that almost no assumptions still lead to a complete solution (+1).

Comment: This was such a fun problem to work on and I'm so happy you cracked this nut. Well done!

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze You're welcome, and I look forward to reading more of your answers if they are all as good as the one here.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thanks for the compliment , and I hope you will come across even better problems as you explore MSE!

Answer (score 5):

Serveral good ideas have been presented in the solutions and comments. But I was surprised that seemingly noone tried to use calculus. Therefore I have tried to fill the gap.

However, as @PierreCarre correctly observed in a comment this is an incomplete solution to the problem of finding all functions for which the equation

$$f(xf(y)+f(x)+y)=xy+f(x)+f(y)\tag{1}$$

holds, because it assumes that all derivatives of $f$ with repect to its argument exist.

But it might be still of interest.

**Main idea**

Under this supposition taking successive derivatives with respect to $x$ at the point $(x,y) = (-1,-1)$ gives
$$f(-1) = -1$$
$$f'(-1) = +1$$
$$f''(-1) = 0$$
and all higher derivatives of $f$ vanish at this point.
Hence $$f(x) = x$$

**Derivation in detail**

The main non trivial point is to show that for $n\ge2$ the n-th derivate of $f$ at $x=-1$ vanishes.

Let

$$h(x,y) = f(g(x,y))- r(x,y)$$

where

$$g(x,y) = x f(y) + f(x)+y$$
$$r(x,y) = x y + f(x) + f(y)$$

then the defining equation becomes

$$h(x,y) = 0$$

For the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ we have

$$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}h(x,y) = 0$$

Let us write down the derivatives of $g$ and $r$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,y) = f(y)+f'(x)$$
$$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}g(x,y) = f''(x), \text{for }n\ge2$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}r(x,y) = y+f'(x)$$
$$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}r(x,y) = f''(x), \text{for }n\ge2$$

Now the derivatives of $h$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}h(g(x,y)) = f'(g)g_x-r_x$$
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}h(g(x,y)) = f''(g)(g_x)^2+ f'(g)g_{xx}-r_{xx}\\=
f''(g)(g_x)^2+ f'(g)f''(x)-f''(x)$$
$$\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3}h(g(x,y)) = 
f^{(3)}(g)(g_x)^3+ 2f''(g)g_x g_{xx} + f''(g)g_x f''(x) + f'(g) f^{(3)}(x)-f^{(3)}(x)\\
=\Theta(g_x) +f^{(3)}(x)(f'(g)-1)\\$$

here $\Theta(g_x)$ comprises terms containing at least one factor $g_x\text{, }g_{xx} \text{ and higher}$

$$\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}h(g(x,y)) = 
\Theta(g_x)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f^{(3)}(x)(f'(g)-1)\\=
\Theta(g_x) + f^{(4)}(x)(f'(g)-1)+f^{(3)}(x)(f'(g)g_x)\\=
\Theta(g_x) + f^{(4)}(x)(f'(g)-1)
$$

and generally for $n\ge2$

$$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}h(g(x,y)) = 
\Theta(g_x) + f^{(n)}(x)(f'(g)-1)
$$

Now, as suggested first in a comment, we look at the point $P=(x=-1, y=-1)$

We have

$$g(p) = x f(y) + f(x)+y\to - f(-1) + f(-1)-1 = -1$$

$$r(p) = x y + f(x) + f(y)\to 1 + 2f(-1)$$

Now for $h$ we have at $P$

$$h(P)=f(g)-r \to f(-1) - 1 - 2f(-1)= - 1- f(-1) $$

Letting $h=0$ leads to

$$f(-1) = -1$$

Next, for $h_x$ we get

$$h_x(P)=f'(g)g_x-r_x=f'(g)(f(y)+f'(x))-(y+f'(x))=f'(-1)(f(-1)+f'(-1))-(-1+f'(-1))=f'(-1)(-1+f'(-1))-(-1+f'(-1))=-f'(-1)^2-2f'(-1)+1=(f'(-1)-1)^2$$

Letting $h_x=0$ gives

$$f'(-1)=+1$$

Next

$$h_{xx}=f''(g)(g_x)^2+ f''(x)(f'(g)-1)$$

observing that $g_x(P)=0$ and $f'(P)=-1$ we have

$$0=h_{xx}|_P=-2 f''(-1)$$

And all derivatives with $n\ge2$ vanish at $P$ as seen from

$$0=h_{x^{n}}= \Theta(g_x) + f^{(n)}(x)(f'(g)-1)|_P=-2 f^{(n)}(-1)
$$

Comment: Since no assumptions are made with respect to the regularity of $f$, your answer is incomplete. You only established that the only analytic function that satisfies the relation is $f(x) = x$.

Comment: Just spotted the "To be completed soon"...

Comment: @ PierreCarre You are right, this is a limited solution. I would appreciate to see a solution in a more general family of functions.

Comment: @PierreCarre Here's an example of a pathological case of an innocently looking functional equation (far beyond my range): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356645/i-need-to-find-all-functions-f-mathbb-r-rightarrow-mathbb-r-which-are-conti?rq=1