# $\sum a_n$ converge but $\sum \sin(a_n)$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

**Problem :**

Show there is $a_n$ such that

$\sum a_n$ converge but $\sum \sin(a_n)$ diverges

or show the $a_n$ doesn't exist.

---

**My Attempt**

Since $$|\sin x| \le |x|$$

$a_n$ changes its sign (If $a_n > 0$ or $a_n<0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we know $\sum \sin (a_n)$ converge since $\sum a_n$ converge.)

I tried to use a local inverse of $f\colon x \to x - \frac{x^3}{6}$ at $x=0$ because $$\sin x \approx x - \frac{x^3}{6}$$

So I think there is $a_n = f^{-1}(x_n) \quad (x_n \to 0)$ such that

$$\sum a_n<\infty,\quad \sum \sin(a_n) \approx \sum x_n = \infty$$

But I can't construct it, or I was wrong.

So my question is I want to know an example of $a_n$ and how to construct it if $a_n$ exists.

If $a_n$ doesn't exist, I want to know how to prove it.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Since $\sum_{n} a_{n}$ converges then $a_{n}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$. Hence $\frac{\sin a_{n}}{a_{n}} \underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}1$. Then $\sum_{n} \sin a_{n}$ converges if $a_{n}>0$ by comparision test.

Comment: @Alex OP already noticed that if $a_n>0$ then $\sum \sin(a_n)$ converges. So they are asking about the case that $\sum a_n$ is conditionally convergent.

Comment: Take $a_{3n-2} = 1/n^{1/3}$, $a_{3n-1} = 1/n^{1/3}$, and $a_{3n} = - 2/n^{1/3}$. Then $\sum a_n$ converges (conditionally) to $0$ but, since 

$$\sin(1/n^{1/3}) + \sin(1/n^{1/3}) - \sin(2/n^{1/3}) = 1/n + O(1/n^{5/3}),$$

the sum $\sum \sin a_n$ will diverge by comparison to the harmonic series.

Comment: Only a remark: notice that $\sin x= x-\frac{1}{6}x^{3}+\mathcal{O}(x^{4})$. Then using the @user994373's answer $\sum \sin a_{n}=\sum a_{n}-\frac{1}{6}\sum a_{n}^{3} +\mathcal{O}\left( \sum a_{n}^{4}\right)$ diverges because $\sum a_{n}^{3}$ diverges.

Comment: This is also relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1332433/998310

Comment: @snaw:  Oops, sorry... comment deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The example itself**

To expand on the great example that was presented in the comments, if we take
$a_n=b_nc_n$ where $b_n=\lfloor n/3 \rfloor^{-1/3}$ and $c_n=1,1,-2,1,1,-2,\ldots$, then since the partial sums of $\sum c_n$ are bounded and $b_n\to 0$ monotonically, then by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) the series $\sum a_n$ converges.

Now for $\sum \sin(a_n)$. Notice that every $3$ consecutive terms of $b_n$ which start with $n=3k$ are equal to one another. (So that in $a_n=b_nc_n$ the sum of every consecutive triplet starting with $n=3k$ is zero). Let's see what kind of cancellations we get for $\sin(a_n)$. If we sum each $3$ consecutive terms
$$\sin(k^{-1/3})+\sin(k^{-1/3})-\sin(2k^{-1/3})$$
using the Taylor series expansion $\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+O(x^5)$, we get
$$
2\cdot(k^{-1/3}-k^{-1}/3!+O(k^{-5/3})) -(2k^{-1/3}-8k^{-1}/3!+O(k^{-5/3}))$$
which simplifies to $-\frac{10}{3!}\cdot \frac{1}{k} + O(k^{-5/3})$.

This means that the partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^m \sin(a_n)$ for $m$ a multiple of $3$ equals $$-\frac{10}{3!}\sum_{n=1}^{m/3} \frac{1}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{m/3}O(n^{-5/3}),$$ so as $m\to\infty$ the right sum converges (since it is absolutely convergent) and the left sum diverges (since it is a constant times the harmonic series). Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(a_n)$ diverges.

---

**Motivation for constructing this example**

1. On first glance it seems reasonable to guess that it wouldn't be possible to construct such $a_n$, since $\sin x \sim x$ for $x\to 0$. This indeed shows that there can be no such $a_n$ with positive terms, as was mentioned in the question. However, when $a_n$ has alternating terms it is possible that we will get different kind of cancellations in $a_n$ and $\sin(a_n)$, because while $\sin(a_n)$ tends to $0$ "at the same rate" as $a_n$ does, these are of course not the exact same terms -- and so it is reasonable that we can construct a special $a_n$ such that the cancellations of $a_n$ and $\sin(a_n)$ would yield different results. This is my intuition for why it *might* be possible to construct such $a_n$.
2. In order to try and get different cancellations for $\sin(a_n)$ we use the Taylor series of $\sin x$. The idea is to try and get the linear terms to cancel out, and the $x^3$ terms not to cancel each other and to diverge, and the $x^5$ terms (and above) to converge. So other than the constants that will guarantee the cancellation of the linear terms, let's try $a_n$ which is roughly of the form $n^{-\alpha}$ but such that $3$ consecutive terms are equal (see why $3$ below) so we take $\lfloor n/3 \rfloor^{-\alpha}$. We need $n^{-3\alpha}$ to diverge and $n^{-5\alpha}$ to converge, that is, we want $3\alpha\leq 1$ and $5\alpha>1$ so any $\frac{1}{5}< \alpha\leq\frac{1}{3}$ will do, and we choose $\alpha=\frac{1}{3}$. Now in order to get the linear terms to cancel out we multiply $\lfloor n/3\rfloor ^{-1/3}$ by the constants $1,1,-2,1,1,-2,\ldots$. (The simpler choice of $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$ and $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ would not work, because that would make the $x^3$ terms, and all subsequent terms, cancel out each other as well. This is clear without resort to Taylor series, $\sin x$ is an odd function, so for $a_n=(-1)^n\lfloor n/2 \rfloor^{-\alpha}$ we get that the terms of $\sin(a_n)$ cancel each other in pairs just the same way as the terms of $a_n$ do).
3. There is nothing special about $\sin(x)$, in the sense that for *any* non-linear $f(x)$ it is possible to find a convergent $\sum a_n$ such that $\sum f(a_n)$ diverges. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1332433/998310) for details. I haven't read the answers yet but I believe the overall intuition should be the same-- that it is plausible that we can use non-linearity of $f(x)$ to get different cancellations for $\sum a_n$ and $\sum f(a_n)$.

Comment: Thanks for an example! But I don't know the motivation to construct it.

Comment: @bFur4list I tried adding some motivation, let me know if this makes sense. Notice that I fixed an error: the sequence should be $a_n=b_nc_n$ where $b_n=\lfloor n/3 \rfloor^{-1/3}$ as it is written now, and not $b_n=n^{-1/3}$ as it was previously written, because otherwise the calculation of the cancellation of the linear terms of $3$ consecutive terms of $\sin(a_n)$ would not be correct.

Comment: @bFur4list By the way, if you edit the question to mention that for an example you are looking not only for the formula but also for a motivation of how to construct it, then the question might get re-opened, because I don't think this is addressed in the other question which this question was marked a duplicate of. (If you do this then in your edit mark the box that says that it should be considered for re-opening.)